# How do I update time on multiple rows using javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using the fromNow function from moment.js library to display time elapsed from a specific date/time (e.g. '16 hours ago'). I use this within a table on multiple rows within my web app.

This part works fine, but I need the time to count continuously and for several rows (50 - 60 and growing).  How do I get the time to count continuously and efficiently?  I say efficiently because, I've read that using interval may be a bad idea so I'm not sure and I need help understanding.

This is how I create a cell which holds the elapsed time:

```
newCell = row.insertCell(++cellIndex);
  newText = document.createTextNode(moment(data.checkintime).fromNow());
  newCell.appendChild(newText);
```

Comment: one quick way is to re iterate all the rows and set their values again but that's not good because you need to update it very frequently. Have you looked at observables? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code you posted is correct, you can save the updated time in a variable and update all the rows.  In that way, it's the same time that will display for all the rows and that time would just have to be done in one time:

```
var updatedTime = moment(data.checkintime).fromNow();
newCell = row.insertCell(++cellIndex);
newText = document.createTextNode(updatedTime);
newCell.appendChild(newText);
```

Comment: Each row will have it's own specific start time so the durations will be different.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the timestamp to continuously update, look into a library such as [TimeAgo](http://timeago.yarp.com/).

With your current code, simply change the text node to match timaeago's syntax `<abbr title='{timestamp}' class='timeago'>` and add the following javascript to the bottom of your page

`jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});`

This will continuously update the timestamp ("a moment ago", "2 minutes ago"....) which I believe is what you're looking for

Comment: This looks like what I need.  I'll give it a shot and comment.

Comment: Was able to get it working thank you.  It displays the first row immediately, and roughly 3 seconds to display the other 50+ records though :/ I'm not sure what I can do about that.

Comment: Update: Seems to be browser related.  On firefox, I see slowness.  On Chrome all is well.  On IE, at first it wouldn't load at all until I hit refresh.  Then it was fast.

Comment: Seems it was some plugins in firefox causing the slowness.  Not sure which one yet but I disabled them all and it's really good now.

Comment: @user3389171 Great, glad you got it working. Can you accept the answer if it worked for you? Also if you found out which plugin is causing issues, I'll add it to the answer as a 'warning'

Comment: I tried accepting it as soon as it worked but got this: "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly-displayed post score."  Strangely enough, firefox is acting nice now. I only had 3 plugins: Firesizer 1.7.1-signed, Jira Capture 2.7.1.0, and View Cookies 1.12.1-signed